# org.json.JSONException: No value for price

Tags: java, android, json

I get result json and parse in android. Exception has happened with a message: org.json.JSONException: No value for price

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for price
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
```

My java class

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// tracks JSONArray
JSONArray albums = null;

// Album id
String album_id = null;
String song_id = null;

String album_name, song_name, price;

// single song JSON url
// GET parameters album, song
private static final String URL_SONG = "my url";


// ALL JSON node names
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_ALBUM = "name";     // album
...
try {
       JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
       if(jObj != null){
            song_name = jObj.getString(TAG_NAME);
            album_name = jObj.getString(TAG_ALBUM);
            price = jObj.getString(TAG_PRICE);
       }
 } 
 catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

My json URL:

```
{
  "id": "551"
  "name": "Rent Disk"
  "price": "3233333"
  "album_id": "3"
  "album": "Michael"
}
```

How to fix this exception? thank so much !!

Comment: Your json invalid

Comment: check your json on this site:- http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put a check like this before putting value

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
if(jObj != null) {
    if(jObj.has(TAG_NAME)) {
        song_name = jObj.getString(TAG_NAME);
    }
    if(jObj.has(TAG_ALBUM)){
        album_name = jObj.getString(TAG_ALBUM);
    }
    if(jObj.has(TAG_PRICE)){
        price = jObj.getString(TAG_PRICE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and back

Comment: have you checked Mr. @luongkhanh?

Comment: Hi Mr Rahul Khurana, I have fixed this error, I get correct json format and It's worked ! I also test and debug base on your code, it perfect ^^ thank you so much

Comment: So glad to help you

Answer (score 4):

**[JSONException](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html)**

> Thrown to indicate a problem with the JSON API

**FYI**

```
 {
  "id": "551"
  "name": "Rent Disk"
  "price": "3233333"
  "album_id": "3"
  "album": "Michael"
}
```

Post your Json **[Here](http://jsonprettyprint.com/)**

If above is your json then **it is not valid** .

For your requirement you should use  **JSONObject**  `.has("") and .isNull("")` method .

**Edited**

Your perfect Json is

```
{ "id": 551, "name": "Cho thue xe Toyota5", "price": "3233333", "album_id": "3", "album": "Huyndai" }
```

Try with this

```
 JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(json);
 String getName = myJson.optString("name");
 int getID= myJson.optInt("id");
```

Comment: Hi guy, I have check and see that my json was lacked comma: 
valid:
{
 "id": 551,
 "name": "Cho thue xe Toyota5",
 "price": "3233333",
 "album_id": "3",
 "album": "Huyndai"
}
invalid:
{
  "id": "551"
  "name": "Rent Disk"
  "price": "3233333"
  "album_id": "3"
  "album": "Michael"
}

Comment: @luongkhanh nope ,Still invalid

Comment: Yes, ex: id = 551 is Ok, but id="551" not Ok, Do you have another solution for me ?

Comment: @luongkhanh sorry ,Your `{ "id": 551, "name": "Cho thue xe Toyota5", "price": "3233333", "album_id": "3", "album": "Huyndai" }` is perfect now

Comment: Yes I see, but I don't know how to change json correct

Comment: Im review my code as your advice from server, i will back to you

Comment: Hi Mr IntelliJ Amiya, I have fixed this error, just need to get correct json format and it's worked ! thank so much !